# NSOperationQueue with synchronous NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue

Building on an [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224811/nsoperationqueue-trouble-understanding-the-order) question:
I have an `NSOperationQueue` that looks like this:

```
NSBlockOperation *block1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [someObject someSelector];
    }];

NSBlockOperation *block2= [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [someObject anotherSelector];
}];

[block2 addDependency:block1];
[queue addOperation:block1];
[queue addOperation:block2];
```

Now, inside `someSelector` I have:

```
returnData = [requesterObj getDataWithURL:(NSString*)url];
```

where `getDataWithURL` contains something like:

```
NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:timeout];
NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
```

Now, when I add breakpoints, it appears that the second block is being called before the `NSURLConnection` from the first block finishes. Presumably because the call to `getDataWithURL`, is itself asyncronous. What's the best way to make sure that the first block doesn't complete before that request returns. Should I try using an `NSInvocation` to put the data inside `returnData`?

Comment: This should be solved by setting the dependencies correctly. In the posted code you are **starting** block operations without setting dependencies! So what do you mean with _Assume also that I have set up dependencies..._ ? Can you post the relevant code where you set them?

Comment: No, dependencies are set correctly. The problem is that `NSBlockOperation` has no way of knowing that async request is not yet completed – it assumes that all stuff is finished after the block ends.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSBlockOperation *block1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [someObject someSelector];
}];
```

This creates a 'standard' block operation. This operation is considered finished (`[block1 isFinished]` is true) after the block is executed, even though the async network operation isn't complete from user point of view.

Since you don't want this, you need to subclass `NSOperation` and *explicitly* tell it when your operation finishes by overriding its `start`:

```
- (void)completeOperation {

    self.finished = YES;
    self.executing = NO;
}

- (void)start {

    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        [self completeOperation];
        return;
    }

    self.executing = YES;
    [self main];
    // this is where operation is set to finished in NSOperation 
}

- (void)main { 
    [someObject someSelectorWithCompletionBlock: ^() { 
        [self completeOperation]; 
        // retain cycle may exist unless completion block is destroyed afterwards
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [grand central dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html), as it makes the code pretty self-explanatory. This code will call the two selectors in sequence (from another thread) and then call `doneSelector` on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    // These will be called in sequence on a background thread
    [someObject someSelector];
    [someObject anotherSelector]

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // These will be called on the main thread after the above are done
        [someObject doneSelector];
        NSLog(@"Finished operation");
    });
});
```

Comment: If the author is correct that *the call to getDataWithURL, is itself asynchronous*, this GCD example will also execute `[someObject anotherSelector]` while async request is being processed. In fact, that's **exactly** where `NSOperation` helps!

Comment: `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:]` is not an asynchronous request. That method should block the thread.

Comment: Yes, but based on the author's observations I assume that there is more async stuff going on (or this phrase is misleading).

Comment: Anyway, synchronous calls shouldn't be used at all, they will block the whole thread; GCD tries to minimize number of threads used, so you may affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for your situation, I would just make things simpler and do the following.

```
NSBlockOperation *block1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [someObject someSelector];
    [someObject anotherSelector];
}];
[queue addOperation:block1];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first posted [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224811/nsoperationqueue-trouble-understanding-the-order), I guessed you might have been dealing with asynchronous network requests, and if you want operations with asynchronous network requests, one generally solves that wrapping such network request within a subclassed `NSOperation` [as I discussed in the answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225013/1271826) (and as ilya subsequently also described here).

Your question here suggested that you are calling `sendSynchronousRequest`. If that was all you were doing, then that `NSOperation` subclassing pattern would not be needed, and you should be able to use `addDependency` without incident. But, it looks like you discovered that `getDataWithURL` was, itself, submitting that `sendSynchronousRequest` to its own operation queue, effectively making it asynchronous. You correctly identified that if you get rid of that redundant operation queue logic from within `getDataWithURL`, then then your problem is resolved and no `NSOperation` subclassing is needed.

But, I wouldn't be too quick to dismiss this subclassed `NSOperation` pattern, though, because `sendSynchronousRequest` has some limitations with which you might to encumber yourself. Namely, those requests can't be canceled. Likewise, you can't get progress of those requests as they're underway, nor handle any advanced features like challenge-response authentication or the like. You might not need any of these features, but because of these limitations, many of us generally shy away from `sendSynchronousRequest` (and `sendAsynchronousRequest`, too).

Longer term, you might find yourself drawn to [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)-based network calls which addresses these limitations. In which case, this `NSOperation` subclass pattern may again become useful. Or, even better, consider using a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) that provides an `NSOperation`-based networking solution, but does a lot of this grunt work for you.